# Como eliminar una herramienta clonada de git hub en linux manjaro

Tags: linux, línea-de-comandos

Hola soy un poco nuevo en esto de Linux y me he decidio a probar manjaro, estaba probando unas herramientas de pentesting pero no todas las herramientas me han agradado y deseo desintalar algunas asi como las dependencias que trae cada una. he intentado probar el comando

```
sudo pacman -R "nombre del programa"
```

con el nombre de la carpeta de la herramienta pero no se desintala, tambien pense en eliminar la carpeta donde tengo la herramienta con el comando -rm -r "Nombre de la carpeta" pero no se si sea suficiente. y si con eso se eliminen las dependencias que instalo el programa.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer una distinción clara entre lo que es clonar un repositorio de GitHub y lo que es instalar un paquete desde un repositorio de tu distribución de Linux, en este caso Manjaro(Archlinux).

- Cuando clonas un repo de GitHub a efectos prácticos haces "copy&paste" del contenido a una carpeta de tu elección pero no "instalas" nada.
- Cuando usas `pacman` u otro gestor de paquetes instalas el programa en cuestión en tu sistema operativo como cualquier otra aplicación en las carpetas correspondientes.

Así pues `pacman -R` no te funciona porque esa carpeta no es un programa instalado ni gestionado por él; es solo eso, una carpeta que simplemente has clonado de github. Borrando la carpeta sería más que suficiente.

Otra cosa sería que esa carpeta contuviera un paquete y lo hubieras instalado con pacman o con otro gestor. En ese caso tendrías que saber el nombre del programa (no la carpeta) y eliminarlo con el gestor con el que lo instalaste. Soy bastante ambiguo en la explicación porque tu pregunta es ambigua y un poco confusa.